# Unable to display taxvat builtin magento field in addresses

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community

In Magento 1.7 and 1.8 there are 2 "eav_attribute" regarding VAT: 'vat_id' and 'taxvat'.
I can display the vat_id on customer address simply from system -> configuration -> customer configuration adding in the address templates:

```
{{depend vat_id}}VAT ID: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

And it works fine. 
if I try the same thing with the  'taxvat' field

```
{{depend taxvat}}CF: {{var taxvat}}{{/depend}}
```

it doesn't work...

I think that it depends from the file

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
```

so I create a custom module and added my config.xml, then I tried to edit the configuration to make the taxvat field like the vat_id field, but still it doesn't work.
What's the best practice to display this builtin field in the address?

Comment: just found that http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33137/ but also firstname and lastname depending from customer...

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the `taxvat` is not working is because there is not attribute taxvat saved as part of the address. You can see this by looking into the table `eav_attribute` and filter on `entity_type_id` where the id is 2 (note that this is in the default data the address id)

You can either make a new attribute on the address, but that is a lot of work. What you could do instead is to look at the event `customer_address_format` here you can add items to the address object before rendering so you should be able to add the taxvat from the customer to the address.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to add the vat_id (taxvat) as variable in address :

#### app/code/local/ClientName/Sales/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <customer_address_format>
                <observers>
                    <clientname_sales_customer_address_format_observer>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>clientname_sales/observer</class>
                        <method>addAdditionalDataToAddress</method>
                    </clientname_sales_customer_address_format_observer>
                </observers>
            </customer_address_format>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

#### app/code/local/ClientName/Sales/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class ClientName_Sales_Model_Observer
{

    /**
     * Add vat_id in address
     *
     */
    public function addAdditionalDataToAddress(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $address = $event['address'];
        $orderData = $address->getOrder()->getData();
        $address->setData(
            array_merge(
                $address->getData(),
                array(
                    'vat_id' => $orderData['customer_taxvat'],
                )
        ));
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in your address template :

```
{{depend vat_id}}VAT ID: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```